# Actor not scaling from center

Tags: libgdx

I want to scale the start button from the center with initially scaled to 0.3 times.

```
    start = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(startTex)));
    start.setTransform(true);
    start.setScale(0.3f);
    start.setOrigin(Align.center);
    start.addAction(forever( sequence(scaleTo(1.5f,1.5f,1f), scaleTo(1, 1, 0.5f), delay(0.5f)) ));
    table.add(start).expandX().colspan(2).size(start.getWidth()*0.3f);
```

It scales the button but not from the center.

When I remove size method from above, button scales from the center, but it starts from its initial size rather than 0.3 times.
I am stuck at this. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try moving the SetOrigin to before your first scale call?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, I have tried that, but `setScale()` method is of no use when we add it in table.